# Why is my MVC controller returning JSON wrapped in quotes and unformatted?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm not getting a proper JSON return.  Any ideas?  Is there a better way to do this?  Do I need the DataTable?

```
public JsonResult ReportData(string pdfID)
{
    string sqlConnectionString = @"ConnectThatThangStuff;";
    string queryString = @"SELECT stuffs FROM Thingy;";

    var json = string.Empty;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    }

    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And what do I get for my efforts?  This crap:

```
"[{\"transid\":1111,\"FromEmailAddress\":\"email@email.com\",\"Name\":\"bob doe\",\"EmailAddress\":\"email@email.com\",\"CreateDt\":\"4/08/2021\",\"ExpirationDt\":\"5/08/2021\",\"Status\":\"Complete\",\"FinalDt\":\"4/09/2021\"},{\"transid\":22222,\"FromEmailAddress\":\"email@email.com\",\"Name\":\"bill doe\",\"EmailAddress\":\"email@email.com\",\"CreateDt\":\"4/08/2021\",\"ExpirationDt\":\"5/08/2021\",\"Status\":\"Ready\",\"FinalDt\":null}]"
```

I need the JOSN to build a jQuery DataTable in my view.  If there is an easier way to go from SQL Query -> jQuery DataTable, I'll take that also.

I'm not using Entity Framework.

Comment: If you need to serialize a `DataTable` using `System.Text.Json` see [Serialize DataSet with current version of System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59780446/3744182).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return Json(object);` handles the serialization for you, try passing `dt` directly in there

Comment: Ok thanks.  When I do this, I get: `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.`

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you are serializing twice.  You can fix this issue while avoiding the circular reference problem by using the [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.content?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method instead of the [`Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method in your controller:

```
// serialize using Json.Net (handles DataTable cleanly)
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);   

// Return the already-serialized JSON string with a content type of application/json
return Content(json, "application/json");
```

You will also need to change your method signature to return a [`ContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) (or [`ActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)) instead of a [`JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Comment: Thanks, this is actually exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the object to JSON twice:

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

```
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In fact, if you look closely, you'll see that your `json` variable is a string.

When you pass the string to the `Json` method, it converts a string to json, which is what you got.

---

I suggest you skip the call to `JsonConvert.Serialize` and just call `Json(dt)`.

However, a small piece of advice: `JsonConvert.Serialize` is calling Newtonsoft Json (JSON.NET) to do the serialization. By calling Json directly, ASP.Net will handle the serialization, and if not properly configured, you might have `System.Text.Json` taking care of serialization for you, which changes a bit how you deal with serialization issues like changing casing, customizing property names and dealing with conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I'm now getting this error: `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.`  Which I will research.